# Outlook 2007 Scheduling Assistant not showing All Day Events

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

We just discovered that when we use Outlook 2007 Scheduling Assistant to pick meeting times:

- We can read one another's calendars, but:
- Outlook is omitting "All Day Events" from the known-busy times.

Insofar as people mark their vacation days that way, it makes it hard to pick a meeting time that doesn't land on somebody's vacation.

A quick search doesn't turn up any discussion on this topic, which leads me to wonder whether either our Exchange Server or our Outlook settings are unusually wrong.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the all day events are set to Busy?  They default having an availability of Free.

Comment: I know this is not the full answer, I recall I had some issue with this Time zones.

Comment: Zoredache's answer is correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer (due to [Zoredache](https://superuser.com/users/2057/zoredache)): by default, All Day Events are marked by Outlook as "Show As: Free", not "Show As: Busy|Out Of Office|Tentative".  If you want to successfully schedule around people's vacations, the vacation-goers have to remember to explicitly set their absence to something other than "Show As: Free".

Comment: This is the correct answer due to Outlook's incorrect behavior. All Day events should NOT default to Free. Especially when created as a meeting.